# algorithmic: the minimum number of operations form M to N with only three operations

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Two positive numbers M and N are given, now you can only do one the following three manipulation to M as follows: 
plus 1, sub 1, or multiply by 2.

- Double: Multiply by 2.
- Decrement: Subtract 1.
- Increment: Plus 1.

each time you can choose any of the three operations.

Input: M = 2, N = 3
Output: 1 (2 + 1)

Input: M = 2, N = 5
Output: 2(2 * 2, + 1)

Return the minimum number of operations needed to display the number Y.

BFS can be used here, but it has a high time complexity, maybe O(2^n). 
As for a simpler problem, leetcode991 using greedy algorithmic. so can any one give a similar one.

Comment: this is changed from the leetcode991: broken calculator

Comment: I didn't get the steps. Can you mention them line by line?

Comment: @vivek_23 take Input: M = 2, N = 5 as an example. multiply M by 2, then you get 4, increment 4 by 1, you get 5. so just 2 steps as needed. Am i clear?

Comment: I meant not the process but the problem statement itself. What does _Double: Multiply by 2_ mean? The formatting is unclear. Can you add it point-wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At each step you're at a number. Think of this in reverse as a trip from N to M. At position x calculate the following:

```
1. abs(x-M)
2. for even x, 1 + abs(x/2-M)
3. for odd x, 2 + abs((x+1)/2-M)
4. for odd x, 2 + abs((x-1)/2-M)
```

Choose the option with the smallest result, note the operation(s), and repeat. Stop if you ever choose the first option.

E.g., M=17, N=39

```
x=39, the (1,2,3,4) tuple is (22, n/a, 4, 3), so we choose the fourth option.
x=19, we have (2, n/a, 8, 9), so we choose the first option
```

Now we reverse these to get: 17+1+1 = 19; 19*2+1 = 39

This takes log time.

Comment: what a handsome solution. and as for the steps, if taking the 1st operation, add abs(x-M); if taking the 2nd on, x = x // 2, and add 1; if taking 3rd one, x = (x + 1) // 2, and add 2; if taking 3rd one, x = (x - 1) // 2, and add 2. but i am not familiar with how to prove that. can you give some explanation for the four operations.

Comment: At each step we're answering the question: "is it better to increment our way to the target, or to (in the reverse) divide by 2?" Here, (1) reflects the increment option, and (2) through (4) are the 3 ways of dividing by 2 (since you may need to increment or decrement by 1 first).

Comment: Yeah, i got it. it is a good example on how greedy algorithmic is used. THX